# Как из программы управлять другой, уже запущенной программой

Tags: visual-basic

Здравствуйте!

У меня возникла проблема, которую, похоже можно решить средствами VB. Но 
я не программист, а занимаюсь станками с ЧПУ.

Словом, загружена программа, управляющая работой ЧПУ-станка. В эту 
программу считан текстовый файл с G-кодами, непосредственно управляющими 
работой станка. Все это приходит в движение (начинает работать), когда 
оператор кликает мышкой по кнопке "Выполнить" на экране.

Задача: Как в назначенное время без участия оператора запустить 
обработку (т.е., как в нужное время в определенном месте экрана 
запущенной ранее программы сделать имитацию нажатия левой кнопки мыши).

Буду крайне признателен за помощь в решении проблемы.

-- 
Юрий Селюх.

Comment: @ukaclock, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Рецепт такой:

Вспомогательная программа по таймеру проверяет не наступило ли нужное время, если наступило - с помощью функции FindWindow WinAPI находит окно управляющей программы (по заголовку и имени стиля окна. Имя стиля определяется при помощи утилиты Spy++, WinSight или InqSoft Window Scanner), на нем с помощью функции FindWindowEx находит кнопку "Выполнить" и при помощи функции SendMessage посылает ей сообщение BM_CLICK, т.е. имитирует клик мышкой.

Указанные функции в VB подключаются так:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As Long, _
    ByVal hwndChildAfter As Long, _
    ByVal pszClass As String, _
    ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal Msg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    lParam As Any) As Long
```

Если есть вопросы, задавайте.